# Does TFS with Git VC store the authenticated username next to the commit username?

Tags: git, tfs, tfs-2015

I've recently introduced Git within my company. Git allows users to set their user.name and user.email to whatever value they wish. For auditing reasons, I need to know with certainty which TFS/Active Directory user pushed commits to the TFS on-premise server repository. Does TFS store this information somewhere? Or should I introduce signed commits instead?

Comment: On-prem TFS or TFS online?

Comment: @ThibaultD. on-premise.

Comment: It does not seem to me that TFS integrates Git beyond the strict minimum, you would probably have to go for signed commits. In our case, the e-mail address in not even the same as the user-account's name. In user connects via SSH then he's not even connecting with his own username but using a generic username with an SSH key linked to his account. The complexity of having something like this working seems far beyond TFS's current functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is "**pushedBy**" field. When the user set the user.name and user.email, the "author" and "committer" will use the user.name, but the "pushedBy" still uses the TFS/Active Directory name.

Two ways to check the pushedBy user:

1. Go to Web portal, and select the commit history, you'll see who push this commit.

[image]

2. Use TFS Rest Api to [get a push](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/git/pushes#just-the-push), then you'll get the pushedBy in Response:

**API:**

```
GET http://tfsserver:8080/tfs/CollectionName/_apis/git/repositories/xxxxxxx/pushes/xxx?api-version=1.0
```